# 2008 sentra coolant system

Tags: nissan, coolant-leak, sentra

The overflow tank stays full. The heater only blows cold. I don't think it's thermostat (doesn't overheat until fluid drains out). I don't think it's the water pump (the leak is from the driver side) but maybe.
 The part I think is leaking connects a rubber hose and a metal pipe on the lower driver's side. 
 I'm at a loss.
 If I keep pouring fluid into the radiator it doesn't overheat until it all drains.
 Here's the caveat, my gf was running water instead of coolant and although I thought it was empty it apparently wasn't and it started overheating after a freezing night.

I shut it off until a good thaw, but have developed this leaking connection..any clues anyone?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but WHY don't you fix the leak?

Comment: I cant figure out what is leaking..i think it's coming from a part that connects a rubber hose to a metal pipe, maybe a temperature control device? I can't see exactly it's tucked away pretty good and I'm trying to identify if that part is even relevant to the coolant or if it's coming from somewhere I can't see...ill add pic

Comment: You said there was only water in in the coolant system on a freezing night. How cold did it get? 20 degrees F? If coolant was leaking from the small hose you circled, you could probably see evidence of that.

Comment: In order to provide heat to the passengers, the engine pumps hot coolant to the [heater core](https://www.rockauto.com/info/1063/HT%202024C__ra_p.jpg), which is a small radiator (roughly 12" x 8" x 2" in size) typically located near the glove box. You should be able to find 2 small (1" diameter) hoses entering the firewall at the back of the engine bay. They should be right next to each other. Try locating these hoses. When the engine is hot, these hoses should be hot/warm.

Comment: You will need a radiator pump and put it on a lift to find the leak. The pump will pressurize the cooling system and make it leak, but may need a lift to get under it to spot the source of the leak.